# IPhone App Settings: Settings.bundle vs plist file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, settings.bundle

I'm a bit confused. I'd like to implement some simple settings for my app. I was thinking of just creating a simple plist file. But now I see that there's something called "Settings.bundle" (that also has a plist in there but some other stuff too).

What I'm wondering, which one should I use? (I'm looking for the easiest way)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into NSUserDefaults to store basic app settings.

Answer (score 2):

The settings bundle is for having settings that show up in the system Settings.app. You can use a plist (or easier, NSUserDefaults, which handles the plist for you) to store settings that you change within the app itself.

Comment: Settings.app saves changes to your NSUserDefaults, so it's the easiest thing to do. I'd suggest using Settings.bundle/NSUserDefaults, and moving to a custom settings view when it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Displaying Application Settings](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW17) section in the **iOS Application Programming Guide.**